# what does getline do inside awk?

Tags: awk

I have this following `awk` script that takes the following input file, `input.txt` and produces the output below. Can someone please take the time to break down how this `awk` script works? I've spent a bit of time on it and it's not making a whole lot of sense.

---

**Input:**

`$ cat input.txt`

```
FINISHED
RSYNCJOBNA
20140502 0021 2182096 2082096 6 5
2014820905820902 10:02:15
2014820905820902 10:56:42
0:54:27

INITIATED
RSYNCJOBNA
20140502 0022 3282096 3182096 6 5
2014820905820902 15:31:06
0:06:04 ce eque**
```

**Output:**

```
RSYNCJOBNA|0021|20140502|10:02:15|10:56:42|0:54:27|FINISHED
RSYNCJOBNA|0022|20140502|15:31:06|        |0:06:04|INITIATED
```

**Command to get the above ouput:**

```
awk -v OFS='|' '/FINISHED|INITIATED/ {
        status = $1; getline;
        jobname = $1; getline;
        sequence = $2; date = $1; getline;
        start = $2; getline;
        if (status == "FINISHED") { end = $2; getline } else { end = "        " }
        runtime = $1;
        print jobname, sequence, date, start, end, runtime, status;
    }' input.txt
```

My understanding is that `/FINISHED|INITIATED/ {}` means that the commands inside the curly braces will only be run on lines matching either `FINISHED` or `INITIATED` but as far as I can tell from the output, the script seems to be parsing from *all* lines. What's going on?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Nothing? In that case: Shall we read the awk manual to you? Otherwise: Be precise. Data is read into variables and output in different order.

Comment: I don't know what the getline function in the above command does. And also if we give the pattern like this `/FINISHED|INITIATED/`,  awk searches for the corresponding line and do the operation only on that particular line.But the operation was performed on all the lines. How?

Comment: @HaukeLaging What _Data is read into variables and output in different order_ line means?

Answer (score 18):

The `getline` function reads the next line and moves the script to it. So, consecutive `getline` calls move to the next line. This is perhaps easier to understand with an example:

```
$ cat input.txt
foo
1
2
$ awk '/foo/{print; getline; print; getline; print}' input.txt
foo
1
2
```

As you can see above, the script will process the first line because it matches `foo`. Each call to `getline` will read the line after the current one, so the subsequent `print` calls are printing the next lines.

Comment: But $1 $2 etc reflect the current line still, so the script hasnt really moved to the next line entirely, right?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal no, $1, $2 etc have also changed. Try with `$ seq 10 | awk '/5/{getline; print $1}'` and you will see that `$1` is `6` not `5`.

Comment: Ah I see, but if you do getline var, the behavior is different it seems.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal I don't really know what you mean by that. You might want to ask a new question. I don't know much about the internals of awk.

Comment: I mean if you run awk ' { getline var }' instead of setting $0 and everything to the input, it just sets the variable var to the line and $1 $2 etc remain unchanged.  You would have to use split(var, arr, " "); arr[1], arr[2], etc to re-tokenize var on spaces

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what an `awk` function does then the usual strategy is to have a look at the man page:

> getline
>
> Set $0 from next input record; set NF, NR, FNR, RT

The command block is indeed executed twice only. The other lines are handled via `getline` from within the block.

This could be rewritten to:

```
/FINISHED|INITIATED/ { status = $1; line_number=0; next; }
{ line_number++; }
line_number==1 { jobname = $1; }
line_number==2 { sequence = $2; date = $1; }
...
```

Comment: What happens if the next record is an empty one?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Neither your code nor my alternative looks at the content of the lines (with the exception of `/FINISHED|INITIATED/`). The lines are just counted down. The data must be arranged exactly (from an awk parsing perspective) in the way you have shown otherwise the code will break.