# Find username and password in pcap file

Tags: linux, awk, kali-linux, tshark, pcap

I am completing an assignment where I am given a pcap file to extract data from. The question is, Find username and password in pcap file. This is what I have so far.

```
$ tshark -r assign1.pcap -R 'smtp' -2 | awk '{if($9=="334") print $10}' | base64 -d
```

`tshark` makes the pcap file readable and will only select lines that have the word SMTP in the line.

I then pipe that info into awk, awk will then select the lines I need and then pipe that info to base64 to decode the fields.

The output I am getting is

[image]

But I do not know how to select the actual username and password and decode them. Here is what the file normally looks like, the fields underlined are the username and passwords I need to find and decode. I need to figure out how to find and decode the fields underlined in line 6 and line 8.

[image]

**NOTE:** The pcap file: https://ufile.io/jsfjr

Answer (score 13):

Need a `getline`.  Example

```
$ tshark -r assign1.pcap -R 'smtp' -2 2>&1 | awk '$9=="334"{print $10;getline;print $9}' | base64 -d && echo
Username:abcPassword:def
$
```

#### Reference

- [what does getline do inside awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127664/what-does-getline-do-inside-awk)