# How to skip every three lines using awk

Tags: awk

Could anyone help me on arranging the files? I want to skip every three lines based on the example below using awk.

Current file:

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
```

Desired output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Skip every three or just extract unique values?

Comment: Skip every three. The above is just an example but I will apply it to my own data.

Comment: Of the 4 lines with `a` in your example, which one do you want (the first, the fourth) or are they identical? Are you perhaps looking for the `uniq` command?

Answer (score 7):

```
$ awk 'NR%4==0 { print $0, "in line#", NR }' infile
a in line# 4
b in line# 8
c in line# 12
```

so:

```
awk 'NR%4==0' infile
```

change to `awk 'NR%4==1'` if you want print the first line then skip every next three lines.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '1~4p' filename
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

`awk '{ print; getline; getline; getline}' file`

`getline` moves to next line of file. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127684). When we do nothing, `awk` moves to next line.

In this case three times `getline` is used, but no action is given to `awk`, so three lines are skipped.

Other use of `getline`:

Interestingly `getline < "other_file"` command is used for reading a line from other file.

But use of `getline` is generally not recommended for this type of problem and is not recommended to be used this way populating builtin variables and without testing for its result, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when and how to use `getline`.

Or using `awk` with array:

`awk '{arr[NR]=$0; }END{ for(i=1;i<=NR;i=i+3) print arr[i]}' file`

Here arr indexed on NR(record numbers, i.e. lines) is created in `main` block. In `END` block a for loop works for us.

Comment: @EdMorton your comment is now part of answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
sed -n 'N;N;N;P' file
```

For each line read from `file`, this reads an additional three lines and appends them to the original line with delimiting newline characters using `N`.  The `P` command then prints the original line, up to the first newline character.

Alternatively:

```bsh
sed -n 'p;n;n;n' file
```

This is similar, but first prints the current line and then reads in three other lines that are discarded.

Comment: In second command, three lines are skipped wih `n`. But in `sed 'n;n;n;d' file` three lines are printed before skipping a line with `n`.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh `n` prints the current line and reads the next, so `n;n;n;` would print line 1, 2, and 3, then the `d` would delete the 4th line read by the last `n`. This would then repeat, so you delete every 4th line.